# Centered Logo as well as Nav items in second line

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <style>
      * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    
      body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 15fr .5fr;
      }

      footer {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.85em;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        box-shadow: 0px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

      }

      nav {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }

      nav ul li:hover {
        background-color: grey;
      }

      .brand-logo {
          height: 100%;
      }

      .brand-logo img {
          height: 100%;
      }
      #label {
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
     //   text-align: center;
      }

      .inst {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .nav-wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
      }



      ::selection {
        border: black;
        color: #000;
      }

      ul.dropdown-content.select-dropdown li span {
        color: #000; 
      }

      #cartIcon {
        position: relative;
        text-align : center;
        left: 10px;
      }

      #cartIconNav {
      position: relative;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="" class="brand-logo"><img id="logo" 
        src="https://i.imgur.com/KNOffUU.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" data-target="items" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

        <ul class="center hide-on-med-and-down">

          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Estimator</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li id="cart"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <ul class="sidenav" id="items">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Estimator</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li id="navCart"></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

I'm trying to have my logo centered and the other line also have my menu centered.When trying to center the logo it goes more to the left and my menu items only aligns to the right or left.

ul class="center hide-on-med-and-down"

The line above only seems to align the menu to the right or left even if
center is typed.
Any suggestion on how I can achieve this and where am I going wrong in trying to solve this

Comment: [is this what you wanted?](https://jsfiddle.net/seanb0/qbjnd12m/10/)

Comment: Not exactly, it should look like this link,except with the logo  and menu options being centered.
https://imgur.com/a/HXdsa5C

Comment: looks like you're missing a lot of styles then. also some of your style selectors aren't shown in the html

Comment: Could you like point me in the direction of where I can figure it out...maybe some website that you may know of or YouTube videos?

Comment: Check out flexbox positioning in youtube. It's really helpful for positioning things, using display flex. I'll update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: OK,I'll have a look at videos and website about flexbox

Comment: I've edited my answer with a new link. each css property I changed i've left a comment for you

Comment: Does it matter what website you use to code it,because I am using replit and it is looking like this.It looks fine on your link but when I make the changes in repl it look like this. I have also changed the logo to the one I made for this task.

https://imgur.com/a/fGzuuFd

Comment: It may matter with the size of the image and your browser. Link me your new code and I'll see what's the issue

Comment: https://replit.com/join/qwkyuftm-mithras

Comment: See your styles are being generated by materialize. You should learn that library as we're overriding their styles. They have their own way of doing a navbar layout using classes, similar to bootstrap.

Comment: So if I delete that library would everything work as it should.If not can you make a a comment by which styles I would need to edit.Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I'd keep using materialize and follow their documentation.  The nav, nav ul styles in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/seanb0/prqy5mjn/21/) are still overriding materialize. When you resize the document to mobile-size, the logo centers but our nav styles are overriding their mobile layout too. Remove the nav styles and make sure your html aligns with [their docs](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html) And it's ok since you're new here but make sure you make things more clear when you post a question so you can get better help

Answer (score 0):

Edit: new styles are done mainly using display: flex;
Check my [commented jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seanb0/qbjnd12m/61/)

Main things I changed

```
.nav-wrapper {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
/* Align the inner items with flex
specify that we want them flowing in a single column */

/* Justify content has lots of options for positioning children */
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul li {
    /* Make the li float left, positions them horizontally rather than vertically */
    float: left;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    /* Give a max-width to make the nav buttons smaller */
    max-width: 5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this when I test it 
https://imgur.com/a/HXdsa5C